# Consolidating repetitive queries in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Currently, I have an array with elements and four queries that are similar just using different elements from the array. Roughly the situation seems like this (simplified)

```
$myArray = array('element1', 'element2', 'element3', 'element4');
foreach ( $myArray as $tors_array ) {
    $element[] = $tors_array;
    
}

$query = "SELECT en as country, $element[0] as value 
                FROM administrative
                WHERE year=2021 
                AND $element[0] IS NOT NULL"; 
$result = $DB->query($query);
$query1 = $DB->fetch_object($result);

$query = "SELECT en as country, $element[1] as value 
                FROM administrative
                WHERE year=2021
                AND $element[1] IS NOT NULL";
$result = $DB->query($query);
$query2 = $DB->fetch_object($result);


$query = "SELECT en as country, $element[2] as value 
                FROM administrative 
                WHERE year=2021
                AND $element[2] IS NOT NULL";
$result = $DB->query($query);
$query3 = $DB->fetch_object($result);

$query = "SELECT en as country, $element[3] as value 
                FROM administrative 
                WHERE year=2021
                AND $element[3] IS NOT NULL";
$result = $DB->query($query);
$query4 = $DB->fetch_object($result);
```

Is there another way how this be done instead of repeating the same query only to replace the element?

Comment: Well you could list all four "elements" in the column list, and make the WHERE clause `AND ($element[0] IS NOT NULL OR $element[1] IS NOT NULL OR ...)`. Then you won't be able to use one single alias any more though of course, so the logic to decide which column's value to actually use (for whatever, you neglected to explain anything about the actual _purpose_ of this), would have to be put into the data processing that comes after this.

Comment: The idea is that this array list could be expanded in the feature. Let's say tomorrow I want to add another element. Then I will need to add a new query/ or a new element in the column list as you propose. Actually, this is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: _"Then I will need to add a new query/ or a new element in the column list as you propose"_ - so? Create it dynamically then. You have an array, and arrays can be looped over; `implode` also exists ... (Plus, how would this even be a point to make, when your current approach would require that you "clone" a whole _block_ of instructions each time you'd want to add a new column ...)

Comment: Thanks, @CBroe but I'm afraid that I can't understand you and probably that's why I posted here the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try next query:

```
SELECT 
    en as country, 
    COALESCE($element[0], $element[1], $element[2], $element[3]) as value 
FROM administrative
WHERE year=2021 AND (
    $element[0] IS NOT NULL OR
    $element[1] IS NOT NULL OR
    $element[2] IS NOT NULL OR
    $element[3] IS NOT NULL
);
```

[PHP code for generate query from array](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php8/18550afdbc1b4ef704c1b13994c2eb20/)

Answer (score 0):

this answer is based on the giving in the question

```
function result($myArray = [], $DB= '' , $year='' ){

    foreach ($myArray as $tors_array ) {
        $element[] = $tors_array;       
    }

    $query = "SELECT en as country, :ELEMENT AS VALUE
               FROM administrative
               WHERE year= :YEAR
               AND :ELEMENT IS NOT NULL";

    $stmt = $DB->prepare($query); 

    $stmt->bindParam(':YEAR',$year);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ELEMENT',$element, PDO::PARAM_INT);


    if ($stmt->execute()){
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    return $row;
}

try{
    //$PDO = connect to database
    $myArray = array('element1', 'element2', 'element3', 'element4');
    $year = '2021';
    
    $result = result($myArray,$PDO,$YEAR);
    echo json_encode($result);
 }
 catch (PDOException $e) {

 }
```